# Blank Desktop on openSUSE 12.3 on VMWare Fusion

Tags: opensuse, vmware-fusion

I just installed openSUSE 12.3 on VMWare Fusion 6.  The installation seemed to run without any issues at all.  However, when I start the machine all I see is the default black and green background.  If I click on the background with the mouse, the mouse pointer disappears and I can't interact with the system.  There is no menu bar, and it doesn't seem to accept any keyboard input.  Any ideas?  It works fine with a Ubuntu install.

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem, hitting escape reveals a log that is stuck at purge old kernels...

Answer (score 0):

I used virtual box instead and it is working fine now.

Comment: Good to know.  I ended up sticking with VMWare Fusion... managed to get it working.  Thanks for the update, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was able to drop to a command shell, and apparently that cleared up whatever was causing it to hang (possibly the purge mentioned by PsychoDad).  I restarted and everything came up properly.